# How to apply a setting in a style that will not be overwriiten by a lower-level style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a fairly complicated app, and I have a simple Attached Behavior I want to set on all of my TextBoxes.

The attached behavior works fine, when I set it directly on the element:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{KtWpf:OrdinaryBinding Path=contact}" 
    utilityClasses:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus="True"
    />
```

And it works fine when I set it via an unnamed style in a resource of an element that contains the TextBox:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter
                Property="utilityClasses:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus"
                Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    [...]
```

But if I apply it via an unnamed style in a higher-level resource, it does not apply to elements that have an unnamed style in a lower-level resource:

```
<KtWpf:KorUserControl>
    <KtWpf:KorUserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter
                Property="utilityClasses:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus"
                Value="True" />
        </Style>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            [...]

            <TextBox 
                Text="{KtWpf:OrdinaryBinding Path=contact}" 
                />
```

I'd expect one of two behaviors, either:

1. WPF would search out all of the unnamed styles with TargetType="TextBox", starting at the outermost, applying each setting in turn, perhaps overwriting settings from the outer styles with settings from the inner styles, or
2. WPF would search outwards from the TextBox element until it found the innermost style that would apply, and use that, ignoring all others.

From what I've found in my testing, WPF is doing the second. In this case, what I want is the first.

How do I define a setting in a style that applies globally, even if there are unnamed styles on the TargetType that are defined at lower levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do that. Lower level generic styles will always override upper level generic styles. I don't think there are "multiple styles" elements.

But, you can name the higher level style (make it non-generic), and use BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" in the lower level generic style.

Just my opinion obv.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted, but if that's all that WPF supports, I'll have to live with it.